# Regex Optional Quotation Marks

Tags: regex

I need a regex to detect the character 'a', followed by a space, followed by a word, or words encapsulated in quotation marks. I need to take this word or words, and use them in a substitution, like "b \1"

So:

```
a "foo bar"
a 'foo bar'
a foo
a 
a foo bar
```

should become:

```
b foo bar
b foo bar
b foo
a 
a foo
```

What is the regex I need?

Comment: `"That's the funny thing about strings," he said. "They can include 'quotes' within quotes!"`

Comment: `.replace(/a ['"]?foo\b/, 'b foo')`

Comment: @JackManey Not these ones.
@ Aust I'm not sure how that works with the criteria.

Comment: "Optional" quotation marks ? So you want to remove **all** quotation marks ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Sorry, "a foo bar" should become "b foo" I'll clarify in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
a ('(.+)'|"(.+)"|(\B+))
```

Replaced with:

```
b $2$3$4
```

---

Yes, oddly Python doesn't seem to like empty capturing groups.  Most regex implementations don't have a problem with that, as far as I've seen.  You can always do this in two steps though:

```
temp = re.sub(r"a (['\"])(.*)\1",r"b \2", string)
return re.sub(r"a (\w*)",r"b \1", temp)
```

Or three:

```
temp = re.sub(r"a (\"(.*)\"",r"b \1", string)
temp = re.sub(r"a ('(.*)'",r"b \1", temp)
return re.sub(r"a (\w*)",r"b \1", temp)
```

You could also forego using `sub`, and build the output from the groups yourself, something along the lines of:

```
regex = re.compile(r"^a (([\"'])(.*)\2.*|(\w*).*)$",re.MULTILINE)
matches = re.finditer(regex,string)
for match in matches:
    if match.group(3) is not None:
        print 'b {0}'.format(match.group(3))
    elif match.group(4) is not None:
        print 'b {0}'.format(match.group(4))
```

Comment: I see what it's doing, but python complains that not all groups 2, 3 and 4 are matched. Know a workaround?

Comment: Was rather wondering if there might be a particular target language.  All regex implementations are not created equal.

Answer (score 0):

If quotes are not allowed within quotes something like this can work:

```
perl -pe 's/^a (['\''"]?)(.+)\1$/b $2/' <<EOT
a "foo bar"
a 'foo bar'
a foo
a
EOT
```

Output

```
b foo bar
b foo bar
b foo
a
```

But also works for `a foo bar` (a replaced to b). Is it ok? It does not match to `a ""`.

Comment: No, only a single word when unquoted.

Comment: Then try `perl -pe 's/^a (['\''"])(\w.+)\1$/b $2/; s/^a (\S+)$/b $1/'`. This will not modify `a foo bar`.